# Python AttributeError - 'Category' object has no attribute 'product_set'

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south, attributeerror

My `show_category` view for my ecommerce catalog was fully functional yesterday.  Navigating to domain.com/category/necklaces, for example, would call the `show_category` view and display all my products that are in the necklaces category.  This is accomplished with two tables, products and categories, and their associated "through" tables.

I HAD been using just `syncdb`, but I had to add a new ManyToManyField, and so Django South got involved, I installed that, recreated the database, used django south to manage my migrates, got everything set up and added my categories and products back in the django admin, which all went smoothly.  I checked the database itself in SQL Workbench, and it all looks grand - a perfect recreation of what I had last night, but now using Django South.

But then I navigated to domain.com/category/necklaces where I expected to see my category page listing my one test necklace product.  Instead I got this:

```
AttributeError at /category/necklaces/
'Category' object has no attribute 'product_set'
```

The error is occurring here, in my catalog.views.py:

```
def show_category(request, 
                  category_slug, 
                  template_name="catalog/category.html"):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, 
                          slug=category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
```

But the thing is, this didn't change AT ALL since last night.  I checked the database and YES the product exists, and YES the "through" table is correctly hooking up that product to this category.

Any ideas where I should look?  I ASSUME the error is somewhere in the database, since I basically didn't touch the then-working code, but the database looks so pristine it is hard to say.  Any and all help is appreciated.  I'll be poking around myself in the meantime.

Comment: if you have used a `related_name` in the foreign key reference, `_set` would not work. Can you share your model?

Comment: I would share, but you solved the problem.  Sure enough, related_name snuck into the model.  I'll have to have a talk with the other developer who "didn't touch it since last night...I don't think..."  Thanks karthikr.  Would you like to add it as an answer so I can accept it, or is that not how you deal with comments that solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the comment as an answer for future reference:

If you have used a `related_name` in the foreign key reference, `_set` would no longer work, since django provides `_set` as a default related name, and the custom related name takes precedence

Some documentation on usage of `related_name` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: I voted it up for the added reading - that helped my understanding of the issue which I THOUGHT I fully understood, but had some misconceptions.